# Using local values in function definitions

Tags: go

The following program

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

type TestFunc func()

func main() {
  fmt.Println()
  funcs := []TestFunc{}
  for i:=0; i<5; i++ {
    //i := i
    funcs = append(funcs, func() {fmt.Println(i)})
  }

  for _, f := range funcs {
    f()
  }
}
```

produces an output 5, 5, 5, 5, 5. After uncommenting the line, the program

```
  for i:=0; i<5; i++ {
    i := i
    funcs = append(funcs, func() {fmt.Println(i)})
  }

  for _, f := range funcs {
    f()
  }
```

produces an output 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Is there a better (or an idiomatic) way to pass the current value to a function declaration instead of using `i := i`?

Comment: My head hurts now, think of the developer who's going to pick this up in 6 months. There must be a better way to achieve your goal?

Comment: @DanG, creating a closure over variable in a loop isn't uncommon, there's even an [entry for it in the FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines).

Comment: @JimB Thanks, that provides a better use case in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *is* the idiomatic way of doing it.

You also could pass it as an argument, if you were calling the function immediately.